# Save and update data from SQL Server Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel-2010

I have a SQL Server Databse from which I want to run a query and save the results in MS Excel 2010. Is there a way to refresh the query results in Excel manually?

So far, I have made the connection to the Database and exported it. However, the WHOLE databse is inserted into the Excel but I want the results of a query to be pasted in Excel.

Comment: sql server or mysql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from Excel. Go to the Data tab, Get External Data, From other sources, From SQL Server. You can then refresh the data from within Excel.

A query would need to be saved as a View in SQL Server to appear in the Excel dialog.

Comment: How do I run the query in excel though?

Comment: If you save a view in SQL Server you can select it from the Excel dialog that appears.

Comment: The dialog in excel only asks for a table to be selected not a view. I have saved the view already.

Comment: You might need to reconnect to the server, but when I do this it lists tables and views (even though the dialog just says 'tables').

Comment: My database has separate section called Tables, views etc but the views dont show up when i create the connection

Comment: If I refresh the Excel file, would it automatically run the view again and update the Excel file?

Comment: I haven't got Excel running at the moment but I assume you can just right-click it and chose Refresh. Yeah, right-click and Refresh.